# multiply rewriting rules in .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

how to make links from:
  http://example.com/blog.php?category=1&page=1
to:
  http://example.com/news/1/

I try this:

```
RewriteRule    ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    blog.php?cat=$1&page=$2    [NC,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The **paths** in your URL slug doesn't match the amount of parameters in your rewriterule pattern. `/news/1/` is not going to match `news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?`. Maybe you need to adjust your URL.